# Problems with removing constant features using standard deviation python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I've got a dataset with approximately 2 million rows and 50 columns

I know some of these columns have constant data values - e.g. all rows in that column have the same value

Therefore I thought I would be able to find all constant columns using:

```
for col in data.columns:
    print data[col].std()
```

However the column(s) with 0 standard deviations, return me standard deviations approximately 0.000000012(very small deviations - not 0!)

I have checked all values are constant by running the following

```
print data[data['col3'] != 0.538]
```

Which returns an empty array (showing all values are 0.538 for that column)

Why is the standard deviation therefore not returning 0 for that column?

Sorry for posting such a specific question, but am very confused on how this is working.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Did you try checking for `ddof=0`  as pandas considers `ddof=1` to be the default value?

Comment: You might want to try value_counts or unique as a selector.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a [floating point issue](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

You can use numpy's [`isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) to check whether the standard deviation is close to zero. However, this will also return True when, say, only a couple of values in the series are different from the others. In that case using standard deviation to make sure all values are equal may not be the best way to go. Instead, I'd suggest using a vectorized equality checking with np.isclose (i.e. check if all values are *very* close to the first one). Note that when the numbers are floats, `data[data['col3'] != 0.538]` carries the same risk. You shouldn't check for equality/inequality when floats are concerned.

```
np.isclose(data['col3'], data['col3'][0]).all()
Out[19]: True
```

You can also specify the tolerance for `isclose` based on your real dataset.

Answer (score 0):

For example taken from [link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html):

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
```

Why is that? 1/10 and 2/10 are not exactly representable as a binary fraction. Almost all machines today (July 2010) use IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic, and almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754 “double precision”. 754 doubles contain 53 bits of precision, so on input the computer strives to convert 0.1 to the closest fraction it can of the form J/2**N where J is an integer containing exactly 53 bits. 
And in other words: you can consider your output as zero.